# WPF Datagrid Master Detail MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, datagrid

I have an WPF application. I have two datagrids, one contains a list of indicators and another datagrid that I want to show further details of the selected indicator of the top datagrid.

However my detail grid does not show any data and I can't work out why. I should point out that the master datagrid is populating fine. I have put a break in the setter of the property IndicatorSelected and can see it is being called when an item is selected & the see the data is correct but is just not being displayed in the detail datagrid.

XAML

```
<DataGrid x:Name="dgModels" Grid.Column="0" 
                      ItemsSource="{Binding Path=IndicatorList}"
                      SelectedItem="{Binding Path=IndicatorSelected}"
                      AutoGenerateColumns="false">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Model" Binding="{Binding Name}" IsReadOnly="True"/>
        <DataGridCheckBoxColumn Header="Run" Binding="{Binding Run}" IsReadOnly="false"/>
    </DataGrid.Columns>                                            
</DataGrid>

<DataGrid x:Name="dgParameterInfo" Grid.Column="1"
          ItemsSource="{Binding Path=IndicatorSelected}"
          AutoGenerateColumns="false">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Parameter Name" Binding="{Binding Path=Name}" IsReadOnly="True"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Default Value" Binding="{Binding Path=DefaultValue}" IsReadOnly="True"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Run Value" Binding="{Binding Path=RunValue}" IsReadOnly="True"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Parameter Type" Binding="{Binding Path=ParaType}" IsReadOnly="True"/>
    </DataGrid.Columns>                    
</DataGrid>
```

C#

```
class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    List<IndicatorWrapper> _indicatorList;
    IndicatorWrapper _indicatorWrapper; 

    public List<IndicatorWrapper> IndicatorList
    {
        get { return _indicatorList; }
        set 
        { 
            _indicatorList = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("IndicatorList");
        }
    }
    public IndicatorWrapper IndicatorSelected
    {
        get { return _indicatorWrapper; }
        set
        {
            _indicatorWrapper = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("IndicatorWrapper");
        }
    }

    public ViewModel()
    {
        DatabaseRetrieveSimulator db = new DatabaseRetrieveSimulator();
        IndicatorList = db.GetIndicators();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your IndicatorSelected setter you're calling OnPropertyChanged with IndicatorWrapper...it should be IndicatorSelected :)

Comment: ah! good spot! Although it's still not displaying any data in my detail datagrid

Comment: DataGrid is used to display a collection of items, you're binding it to a single item i.e. DataContext.SelectedItem. If your IndicatorWrapper class has a collection of child items then you can bind the grid to that by changing the binding to something like ItemsSource="{Binding Path=IndicatorSelected.ChildItems}". If you just want to display all the fields for the currently selected item then you'll need to create seperate controls for each field and set up the binding on each to IndicatorSelected.whatever.

Comment: yes that makes sense now. I have changed it to Path=IndicatorSelected.Parameters and it now works & displays properly in both datagrids